# Combining select queries without same count of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to combine two select query, but I get Error

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

First select query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Employees.Name,
    dbo.Employees.Salary
FROM 
    dbo.Employees
```

[image]

Second select query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Employees.Name AS Employee,
    dbo.Employees.Salary AS Salary,
    dbo.Salary.Bonus AS Bonus,
    dbo.Employees.Salary + dbo.Salary.Bonus AS BonusSalary
FROM 
    dbo.Employees 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Salary ON dbo.Employees.Id = dbo.Salary.Employee 
WHERE 
    dbo.Salary.Year = 2023
    AND dbo.Salary.Month = 5
```

[image]

The problem is that I need to combine these two queries. If there are not enough employees in the second query, I need to display them anyway.

I need to display absolutely all employees, regardless of the date

---

I tried to use **UNION** and **EXCEPT**
But I get above error

Comment: Please read [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Seems like changing your INNER JOIN  to a LEFT JOIN should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Employees.Name AS Employee,
    dbo.Salary.forPurchase AS Purchases,
    dbo.Salary.forProduction AS Productions,
    dbo.Salary.forSale AS Sales,
    dbo.Employees.Salary AS Salary,
    dbo.Salary.Bonus AS Bonus,
    dbo.Employees.Salary + dbo.Salary.Bonus AS BonusSalary,
    COALESCE(dbo.Salary.Issued, 'salary was not paid') AS Issued
FROM 
    dbo.Employees
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
        dbo.Salary
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Months
            ON  Salary.Month = Months.Id
            AND Salary.Year  = 2023
            AND Salary.Month = 5       
)
    ON Employees.Id = Salary.Employee
```

But, as you don't actually use the `Months` table, it can be simplified to...

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Employees.Name AS Employee,
    dbo.Salary.forPurchase AS Purchases,
    dbo.Salary.forProduction AS Productions,
    dbo.Salary.forSale AS Sales,
    dbo.Employees.Salary AS Salary,
    dbo.Salary.Bonus AS Bonus,
    dbo.Employees.Salary + dbo.Salary.Bonus AS BonusSalary,
    COALESCE(dbo.Salary.Issued, 'salary was not paid') AS Issued
FROM 
    dbo.Employees
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Salary
        ON  Salary.Employee = Employees.Id 
        AND Salary.Year     = 2023
        AND Salary.Month    = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that you want the whole employee to calculate her salary if it is in the salary table

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Employees.Name AS Employee,
    dbo.Employees.Salary AS Salary,
    dbo.Salary.Bonus AS Bonus,
    dbo.Employees.Salary + dbo.Salary.Bonus AS BonusSalary
FROM 
    dbo.Employees 
left JOIN 
    dbo.Salary ON dbo.Employees.Id = dbo.Salary.Employee  and dbo.Salary.Year = 2023
    AND dbo.Salary.Month = 5
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OTvcZqKf)